# Matrix properties $A^3 + I= 0$ , so $A^{12}=$?

Tags: matrices

Hello I don't have the answers to this but can someone correct me if I'm wrong:

> $A$ in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is such that $A^3$ + Identity matrix = $0$. So $A^{12}$ is equal $A$ ?

Is that correct? Sorry kinda new to this type of exercises.

Comment: $A^{12}=(-I)^4=I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^3=-I\implies A^{12}=(-I)^4=I$.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't see that my bad thank u!!!!!!!!!!